# Asp.net Web-Api: DataAnnotation Validation with complex nested objects

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I am using asp.net web api 2.0 and I have a Dto class that is not plain POCO object. it has other objects as property like following

```
public class TransactionDto{
public string Description{get;set;}
public string TransactionType{get;set;}
//other transaction related properties
public InvoiceDto Invoice{get;set;}
}
public class InvoiceDto{
public DataTime InvoiceDate{get;set;}
public decimal VATAmount{get;set;}
public decimal InvoiceAmount{get;set;}
}
```

Now the scenario is that I want Invoice properties to be `Required` if `TransactionType` is set to `Invoice` and if it is not `Invoice`, I do not care about invoice related properties. How can I achieve this? or do I have to make it plain POCO object with all properties of `Invoice` stuffed into `TransactionDto`?